# How to create multiple colours based on many different ints

Tags: c++, opengl, colors

I would like to make a function that creates an unique color based on  int variables. The problem is range of these variables (from 1 to 10 000).

So i have an array with 10 000 fields of which each has its own ID. And now i need to set color of each field based on that id;

```
void setColor(int ID); // set R G B
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the RGB triples supposed to be unique?

Comment: on second thought I think I may just need to create as many as possible unique RGBs triples. not every of them has to be unique, but still i need many of them, the main point is to get them reliable on that ID variable

Comment: Assuming 24 or 32-bit color, you have 256*256*256 possible combinations, which is well above 10000. Can you explain specifically what you're doing with these colors? Obviously the human eye cannot easily distinguish all of these colors from each other, so I presume you're perhaps trying to do something where you choose a different color for IDs close to each other?

Comment: Are you trying to create an image for visualizing the data (based on color)-- kind of like false-color temperature images? Do the colors need to be related to the data such that nearby values are almost the same color, or can they be totally random?

Answer (score 4):

You have 10,000 possible input options, whereas 256 x 256 x 256 = 16 million output options.
Assuming you want to vary RGB values equally, you can at max use 21 diff values for R,G,B as that would yield 21.5^3 ~ 10000.

So you need to take a step of 256/21 ~ 12 to serve your purpose.

So, basically my point is :

```
int       RGB value
1         0,0,0
2         0,0,12
3         0,0,24
.
..
22        0,0,253
23        0,12,0
.
.
.
10000     255,255,255
```

Comment: Note that this can be easily written as `(ID-1)*(0x00ffffff/10000)`, assuming the color is encoded in a 32 bit wide tuple, which is rather commonplace.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the table and build a hash function.
A simple one is:

```
rgb(unsigned x) {
    b = x & 0xFF;
    x >>= 8
    g = x & 0xFF;
    x >>= 8
    r = x & 0xFF;
}
```

The distribution is not nice here: 2^24 - 10000 = 16767216

An alternative hash could calculate distributed = id * 2^24 / 10000.

Comment: Indeed: `b = (x & 0x1F) << 3; x >>= 5;` etc. 5 x 5 x 5 bits is 32768 colors, quite sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is simply to convert the ID into a RGB value directly. It certainly won't result in a visually distinctive range of colours, however.

Comment: yes, thats what i ve been thinking about, but i dont really have an idea how to do it.